# Cannot use break point for TypeScript & Webpack in Visual Studio Code FireFox debugger

Tags: typescript, debugging, webpack

I am trying to use the live debugger to debug my Typescript.

I've check the majority of questions and answers online. Couldn't find a concrete solution for my situation.

Here is my webpack config file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./Scripts/test.ts'],
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './Scripts/dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            include: /\.js$/,
            minimize: true
        })],
    devtool: 'source-map'
}
```

Here is my Typescript config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./Scripts/build/",
    "rootDir": "Scripts",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "jquery",
      "jqueryui",
      "bootstrap-validator"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "Scripts/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

and here is my nodeJS package config:

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxxxxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "watch": {
    "build": {
      "extensions": "ts",
      "patterns": [
        "Scripts"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "npm-watch",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "-vs-binding": {
    "BeforeBuild": [
      "build"
    ]
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bootstrap-validator": "^0.11.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.1",
    "npm-watch": "^0.3.0",
    "ts-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.8",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  }
}
```

I'm using asp.net MVC 5 as the backend server. And here is the folder structure:
[image]

I am trying to debug my Typescript and add some breakpoints. After the backend is up and running, I ran the FireFox debugger: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-firefox-debug
However, those breakpoints are never reached.

It would be great if anyone has the solution for this. Either Visual Studio Code or Visual Studio 2017 would be good if I can debug my typescript there.

Comment: Forgot to attach the launch.json:
{
            "type": "firefox",
            "request": "launch",
            "reAttach": true,
            "name": "Launch Firefox",
            "url": "localhost:1220/typescript",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",        
            "sourceMaps": "server",
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "url":  "webpack:///",
                    "path": "${webRoot}/"
                }
            ],
        }

Comment: I'm having the same problem with debug breakpoints not working in FireFox for TypeScript sources. However, this does work properly in Chrome for me. Is this working in Chrome for you as well?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working via "attach" with the "url" property pointing to localhost, and the "sourceMaps" pointing to "server" for the source map translation.

```
{
       "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
           {
               "name": "Launch Firefox Debugger",
               "type": "firefox",
               "request": "attach",
               "url": "http://localhost:64177/",
               "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
               "sourceMaps": "server"
           }
       ]
   }
```

As a side note, I'm starting the application via the IIS Express extension, and the URL in the launch configuration is the same as the IIS Express URL.